# Ошибка при подключении: Failure test failed: Network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Ниже следующая ошибка:

[image: error]

> Failure test failed: Network adapter could not establish the
> connection

Что было сделано (предпринято):

Менял имя компьютера ставил `localhost`, `hostname` - не помогло. Заходил под логином `sys`, `system` и стандартный пароль oracle, пароль при установки - не помогло. Менял `service` name на `orcl` - не помогло.

Смотрел файл listener.ora. Менял `host` на `localhost` и `hostname`. Убирал `hostname` - не помогло.

```
# copyright (c) 1997 by the Oracle Corporation
# 
# NAME
#   listener.ora
# FUNCTION
#   Network Listener startup parameter file example
# NOTES
#   This file contains all the parameters for listener.ora,
#   and could be used to configure the listener by uncommenting
#   and changing values.  Multiple listeners can be configured
#   in one listener.ora, so listener.ora parameters take the form
#   of SID_LIST_<lsnr>, where <lsnr> is the name of the listener
#   this parameter refers to.  All parameters and values are
#   case-insensitive.

# <lsnr>
#   This parameter specifies both the name of the listener, and
#   it listening address(es). Other parameters for this listener
#   us this name in place of <lsnr>.  When not specified,
#   the name for <lsnr> defaults to "LISTENER", with the default
#   address value as shown below.
#
# LISTENER =
#  (ADDRESS_LIST=
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
#   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=PNPKEY)))   

# SID_LIST_<lsnr>
#   List of services the listener knows about and can connect 
#   clients to.  There is no default.  See the Net8 Administrator's
#   Guide for more information.
#
# SID_LIST_LISTENER=
#   (SID_LIST=
#   (SID_DESC=
#           #BEQUEATH CONFIG
#          (GLOBAL_DBNAME=salesdb.mycompany)
#          (SID_NAME=sid1)          
#          (ORACLE_HOME=/private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3)
#           #PRESPAWN CONFIG
#         (PRESPAWN_MAX=20)
#     (PRESPAWN_LIST=
#           (PRESPAWN_DESC=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(POOL_SIZE=2)(TIMEOUT=1))
#         )
#        )
#       )
    
# PASSWORDS_<lsnr>
#   Specifies a password to authenticate stopping the listener.
#   Both encrypted and plain-text values can be set.  Encrypted passwords
#   can be set and stored using lsnrctl.  
#     LSNRCTL> change_password
#       Will prompt for old and new passwords, and use encryption both
#       to match the old password and to set the new one.
#     LSNRCTL> set password
#   Will prompt for the new password, for authentication with 
#       the listener. The password must be set before running the next
#       command.
#     LSNRCTL> save_config
#       Will save the changed password to listener.ora. These last two
#       steps are not necessary if SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_<lsnr> is ON.
#       See below.
#
# Default: NONE
#
# PASSWORDS_LISTENER = 20A22647832FB454      # "foobar"

# SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_<lsnr>
#   Tells the listener to save configuration changes to listener.ora when
#   it shuts down.  Changed parameter values will be written to the file,
#   while preserving formatting and comments.
# Default: OFF
# Values: ON/OFF
#
# SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER = ON

# USE_PLUG_AND_PLAY_<lsnr>
#   Tells the listener to contact an Onames server and register itself
#   and its services with Onames.
# Values: ON/OFF
# Default: OFF
#
# USE_PLUG_AND_PLAY_LISTENER = ON

# LOG_FILE_<lsnr>
#   Sets the name of the listener's log file.  The .log extension
#   is added automatically.
# Default=<lsnr>
#
# LOG_FILE_LISTENER = lsnr

# LOG_DIRECTORY_<lsnr>
#   Sets the directory for the listener's log file.
# Default: <oracle_home>/network/log
#
# LOG_DIRECTORY_LISTENER = /private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3/network/log

# TRACE_LEVEL_<lsnr>
#   Specifies desired tracing level.
# Default: OFF
# Values: OFF/USER/ADMIN/SUPPORT/0-16
#
# TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER = SUPPORT

# TRACE_FILE_<lsnr>
#   Sets the name of the listener's trace file. The .trc extension
#   is added automatically.
# Default: <lsnr>
#
# TRACE_FILE_LISTENER = lsnr

# TRACE_DIRECTORY_<lsnr>
#   Sets the directory for the listener's trace file.
# Default: <oracle_home>/network/trace
#
# TRACE_DIRECTORY_LISTENER=/private/app/oracle/product/8.0.3/network/trace
# CONNECT_TIMEOUT_<lsnr>
#   Sets the number of seconds that the listener waits to get a 
#   valid database query after it has been started.
# Default: 10
#
# CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER=10
```

```
C:\> lsnrctl status 
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-SEP-2016 10:25:37 
Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle. All rights reserved. 
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=(PORT=1521)) 
 TNS-12541: TNS:no listener 
  TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error 
   TNS-00511: NO listener 
    32-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Comment: Проверьте наличие и содержимое файла tnsnames.ora

Comment: Ну так судя по картинке у вас листенер вообще не поднят. попробуйте его для начала запустить `lsnrctl start` и потом посмотрите опять status, там должно быть написано что он поднят. А т.к. у вас винда - загляните в службы через панель управления->администрирование и убедитесь что оракл запущен

Answer (score 2):

Что делать, если ошибка:

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Вызовете интерпретатор команд как пользователь, который в группе ORA_DBA (тот, кто установливал БД). Проверте прослушиватель:

```
C:\> lsnrctl status

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener

C:\> lsnrctl start

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Запустите SQL*Plus и убедитесь, что соединение теперь возможно:

```
C:\> sqlplus me/me@localhost:1521/orcl

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Если получите выше указанную ошибку, то это значит, что БД не запушена. Запустите её:

```
C:\> sqlplus / as sysdba

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.
[...]
Database mounted.
Database opened.

SQL> conn me/me@localhost:1521/orcl
Connected.
```

Всё, теперь проверте в SQL Developer:

> Status: Success